# how to find cordova.jar in latest version of phonegap 2.9.1?

Tags: cordova

I download latest version phonegap-2.9.1 zip file but it not contain cordova.jar and when i search on google the  i got on answer like navigate folder to lib/android/framework directory and fire command 
**android update project -p . -t android-17** 
then 
**ant jar**

but not working. please anybody tell me how to find cordova.jar from phonegap-2.9.1 .

Comment: Why isn't it working? What kind of error messages did it give you? You need to have `ant`, the android tools, and Java JDK 1.5+ on your $PATH in order to build the android jar file.

Answer (score 19):

First, you need the following requisites, for sure are covered if you have been playing with phonegap/cordova for a while ;)

- Java JDK 1.5 or greater
- Apache ANT 1.8.0 or greater
- Android SDK http://developer.android.com

And then, to generate the ***cordova-2.9.1.jar*** file, follow the next steps:

1. Download and extract the [phonegap-2.9.1.zip](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/archive/2.9.1.zip) file.
2. In a terminal/cmd window go inside the recently extracted directory:

   ***$ cd phonegap-2.9.1\lib\android\framework\***
3. Execute the following commands (you need android sdk and ant already configured in your system path):

   ***$ android update project -p . -t android-17***

   If required add the --subprojects parameter:

   ***$ android update project -p . -t android-17 --subprojects***

   You get a message like this:

   Updated project.properties
   Updated local.properties
   build.xml: Found version-tag: custom. File will not be updated.
   Updated file D:\work_NEW\phonegap-2.9.1\lib\android\framework\proguard-project.txt
   Updated and renamed default.properties to project.properties
   Updated local.properties
   No project name specified, using Activity name 'DroidGap'.
   If you wish to change it, edit the first line of build.xml.
   Added file D:\work_NEW\phonegap-2.9.1\lib\android\framework\bin\build.xml
   Added file D:\work_NEW\phonegap-2.9.1\lib\android\framework\bin\proguard-project.txt
4. Finally run:

   ***$ ant jar***

   Blablabla....
   jar:
         [jar] Building jar: xxx\phonegap-2.9.1\lib\android\framework\cordova-2.9.1.jar

   BUILD SUCCESSFUL
   Total time: 4 seconds
5. Done!!!!! The file is ready! And you can find this and other information reading a file inside the phonegap-2.9.1.zip:

   **phonegap-2.9.1\lib\android\README.md**

Comment: your solution now working....when I am firing the command like a "android update project -p . -t android-17" command prompt giving me msg like android is not recognized internal.....

Comment: Hi. You need to add the PATH to your Android SDK platform-tools and tools directory. See the full detail in: [link](http://goo.gl/P4I6q0)

Comment: I get `@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) exception`, KITKAT is higher that 17, but i want  17

Comment: These steps could help me to generate cordova jars.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that in cordova 2.9.1 (and I assume also in phonegap) they made the same change as in version 3.3 :

There is no more cordova.jar, instead you have the sources of cordova in `src\org\apache\cordova\api`.

So if you use eclipse, you have to re-do "import existing android project" with your project's path and it should now find two projects, one for your app and one for the cordova api.

Answer (score 2):

You need to download an extra file called CORODOVA-ANDRIOD. You can download it from https://github.com/apache/cordova-android

Download zip file to your computer and then extract it. 
Look into that folder, you can see FRAMEWORK folder.

Now open CMD Prompt.
navigate to that framework folder (For me it is like this - F:\Softwares\cordova-android-master\framework> )
and write this command

" android update project -p . -t android-17 "

if necessary add --subprojects

" android update project -p . -t android-17 --subprojects "

Remember that android-17 is the api verison. Make sure you have that versions installed. I have android 2.3.3 version api installed. so I changed that -17 to -10.

After compiling android update project,

enter command : " ant jar "
If there are no errors you can see that corodova.jar file in that framework folder.

Answer (score 0):

The cordova.js file is generated by this command line

```
cordova build iOS
```

Or `cordova build android` from your project folder.

Be careful to not copy and paste from a platform to another, the files are not the same !

More info [here](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html)

Comment: not cordova.js, cordova.jar (cordova api library for android). And phonegap 2.9, not 3.0, so no CLI but a zip you download.