# Can't find cordova.jar file in phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova

I am new to `phonegap` the tutorials I have referred to says that there should be a `cordova.jar` file inside the `phonegap-2.9.1\lib\android` path. But I don't have it in this `phonegap 2.9.1` version.
Can I download the `cordova.jar` from anywhere or is there any alternative?
Someone please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: there is no more cordova.jar, instead there is cordova-lib src project

Comment: check my answer in this exact same question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21854568/how-to-find-cordova-jar-in-latest-version-of-phonegap-2-9-1

Comment: someone posted the download link for cordova.jar
I downloaded it and its working fine.
I will try your given solution also

Answer (score 9):

First, you need the following requisites, for sure are covered if you have been playing with phonegap/cordova for a while ;)

- Java JDK 1.5 or greater
- Apache ANT 1.8.0 or greater
- Android SDK http://developer.android.com

And then, to generate the ***cordova-2.9.1.jar*** file, follow the next steps:

1. Download and extract the [phonegap-2.9.1.zip](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/archive/2.9.1.zip) file.
2. In a terminal/cmd window go inside the recently extracted directory:

   ***$ cd phonegap-2.9.1\lib\android\framework\***
3. Execute the following commands (you need android sdk and ant already configured in your system path):

   ***$ android update project -p . -t android-17***

   If required add the --subprojects parameter:

   ***$ android update project -p . -t android-17 --subprojects***

   You get a message like this:

   Updated project.properties
   Updated local.properties
   build.xml: Found version-tag: custom. File will not be updated.
   Updated file D:\work_NEW\phonegap-2.9.1\lib\android\framework\proguard-project.txt
   Updated and renamed default.properties to project.properties
   Updated local.properties
   No project name specified, using Activity name 'DroidGap'.
   If you wish to change it, edit the first line of build.xml.
   Added file D:\work_NEW\phonegap-2.9.1\lib\android\framework\bin\build.xml
   Added file D:\work_NEW\phonegap-2.9.1\lib\android\framework\bin\proguard-project.txt
4. Finally run:

   ***$ ant jar***

   Blablabla....
   jar:
         [jar] Building jar: xxx\phonegap-2.9.1\lib\android\framework\ **cordova-2.9.1.jar**

   BUILD SUCCESSFUL
   Total time: 4 seconds
5. Done!!!!! The file is ready! And you can find this and other information reading a file inside the phonegap-2.9.1.zip:

   **phonegap-2.9.1\lib\android\README.md**

Answer (score 1):

Since 3.x version phonegap has changed a lot. I suggest you to install 3.3 version and create a proyect following the steps described in the offical page.

Also, you can download cordova from cordova web page, add to path, and create a proyect using terminal:

- cordova create app_name
- cordova platform add android || cordova build android

Answer (score 1):

In 3.3.0 version, You can get cordova-3.3.0.jar file by following these steps:
Go to Command Prompt:

$ cd %HOMEPATH%/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/framework

$ android update project -p

$ ant jar

After executing these commands you will get cordova-3.3.0.jar in framework folder i.e.
=> %HOMEPATH%/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/framework/cordova-3.3.0.jar